# How do I pre-process the dataset if the feature ranges are too wide?

Tags: data-science

I have a dataset with 5 features and each column being in a different range of numbers. I have tried using MinMaxScaler and StandardScaler but the accuracy for this multi-class problem is too low.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If StandardScaler and MinMaxScaler don't have the desired affect, then another thing to check for is skewed data:

```
# Check the skew of all numerical features
numeric_feats = all_data.dtypes[all_data.dtypes != "object"].index
skewed_feats = all_data[numeric_feats].apply(lambda x: skew(x.dropna())).sort_values(ascending=False)
print("\nSkew in numerical features: \n")
skewness = pd.DataFrame({'Skew' :skewed_feats})
skewness.head(10)
```

Lower is better. If you get high scores, you can use a transform (log, boxcox, etc) to make the data distribution more normal in shape.

correcting for skew:

```
skewness = skewness[abs(skewness) > 0.75]
print("There are {} skewed numerical features to Box Cox transform".format(skewness.shape[0]))

from scipy.special import boxcox1p
skewed_features = skewness.index

lam_f = 0.15
for feat in skewed_features:
    #all_data[feat] += 1
    all_data[feat] = boxcox1p(all_data[feat], lam_f)
```

Other things to try:

either remove fliers or try RobustScaler()
PowerTransformer()

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html